# MQTT Broker - client disconnected, not authoris

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I created a mosquitto broker on an Ubuntu Linux machine.

when i'm connecting from MQTT.fx software, it looks ok, im able to connect.
but when i'm turning on a device that connect to the broker i'm getting this message on the broker log file :

```
> 1652968173: New connection from 84.110.147.52:22942 on port 1883.
> 1652968173: Sending CONNACK to M_B2:CC:4C:42:A6:FE (0, 5) 1652968173:
> Client M_B2:CC:4C:42:A6:FE disconnected, not authorised.
```

the configuration file has this in it:

```
listener 1883
password_file /home/passwordfile.txt
log_dest file /home/mosquitto_logs.txt
log_type all
```

the passwordfile.txt is ok since i'm able to connect via MQTT.fx

any idea what can be the issue?
is there more relevant information i can share?
Thank you

Comment: Not enough information in the question. You've not given us any information about the client. Also have you run wireshark to sniff what's in the connect packet from the device.